# How can I configure the default transmission rate for 802.11 (“WiFi”)?

Tags: networking, wireless, system-installation, network-manager, configuration

I need to lower the transmission rate of my IEEE 802.11g network interface controller to have acceptable an packet loss ratio (< 0.5 %), otherwise it becomes very high (> 50 % is typical, but it varies). I use NetworkManager to handle my network connection, however it doesn't has a option to lower the transmission rate, so I do it manually through the command line with `sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 1M` every time I power on the computer.

After installation, how can I configure my GNU/Linux system so that the transmission rate is 1 Mbit/s by default (without having to set it manually every time I boot the computer)?. Equivalently, how can I persistently set the transmission rate of my IEEE 802.11g network interface controller to 1 Mb/s?.

Note: I connect only to a single wireless network, but it's not always available every time I power on the computer (this is because I'm not in that location, not a technical problem), and connecting isn't immediate anyway, so I can't work around the problem by making a script that is run when I log-in to the graphic environment and does `iwconfig lwan0 rate 1M`.

Regards and thanks.

Edit: My `/etc/network/interfaces` only has the following (Bear in mind the network is handled by NetworkManager):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: You could add this command as a pre-up script (executed before starting the network interface) for wlan0 in the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. Please post its contents to let me see how we would have to modify it. And make a backup copy of the file in case of a failure.

Comment: @ByteCommander: Thanks you, I pasted the content in my question.

Comment: I'd rather troubleshoot the wireless driver to see why it has such high packet loss.

Answer (score 0):

Please (*after you created the backup copy*) edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to the following state by adding the last three lines:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  pre-up iwconfig wlan0 rate 1M
```

I am not sure if this works as I can't try it out here. Maybe you will lose your wlan0 connection because I missed some necessary additional lines. If this happens, reset the file to the backup state and it should work again as before.